# Problems using easing equations in C# XNA

Tags: xna, c#, easing

I'm having some trouble using the easing equations suggested by Robert Penner for ActionScript (http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/, [and a Flash demo here](http://gizma.com/easing/#l)) in my C# XNA game. Firstly, what is the definition of the following variables passed in as arguments to each equation?

```
float t, float b, float c, float d
```

I'm currently calculating the new X position of a sprite in the Update() loop, however even for the linear tween equation I'm getting some odd results. I'm using the following values:

```
float t = gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
float d = 8000f;
float b = x.Position.X;
float c = (ScreenManager.Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width >> 1) - (x.Position.X + x.frameSize.X / 2);
```

And this equation for linear easing:

```
 float val = c*t/d + b;
```

Comment: Apologies, will add - seems pretty much every library uses these!

Comment: First error... used 'milliseconds' instead of 'TotalMilliseconds'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Firstly, what is the definition of the following variables passed in as arguments to each equation?

The answer was in the link you provided:

- t = current time (starting from 0 and increasing up to the chosen duration)
- d = duration (i.e. total time of the animation)
- b = initial value
- c = change in value (i.e. how much the value should change, or the difference between the final value and the initial value)

Now for your troubles. Let's take a look at the values you chose for `t` and `d`:

```
float t = gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
float d = 8000f;
```

I'm guessing you want your interpolation to take 8 seconds to complete, i.e. 8000 miliseconds. In that case the value of `t` should be starting a 0 on the first frame of the interpolation, and increment a little each frame until it reaches 8000, at which point you should stop updating because the interpolation is complete.

The problem is that you're passing it the value of `gameTime.TotalGameTime` which is the time that has passed **since the game began**, and you're supposed to pass it the time that has passed **since the animation has begun**. Here's the proper solution. First:

```
// Once at the start of the animation
// Note: I'll also use seconds instead of miliseconds
float t = 0f;
float d = 8f;
bool animating = true;
```

And then:

```
// Then once for each frame while the animation is active (i.e. in Update)
if(animating)
{
    t += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    // Don't let time exceed the duration
    t = MathHelper.Min(t, d);

    // Calculate your "val" here
    float val = b + t/d * c;

    // Stop animating if we've reached the end
    if(t >= d) 
        animating = false;
}
```

As for your other values, the value of `c` looks really cryptic and I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. But basically in this given context, `c` should be the amount of units you want your character to move.

Finally, unless you're trying to do some really fancy easing, I would just use one of the XNA's built in methods for this:

- [MathHelper.Lerp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.lerp.aspx)
- [MathHelper.SmoothStep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.smoothstep.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much David - I'd spotted the definitions in the link but just wanted to be crystal clear I hadn't misunderstood anything (which I obviously had!). This is the critical part I managed to comprehensively misunderstand - **which is the time that has passed since the game began, and you're supposed to pass it the time that has passed since the animation has begun.** 'c' is just a distance calculation to centre a sprite in the middle of the screen. Where in a game would the 't', 'd', and 'animating' values normally be stored - within the object being animated?

Comment: Or maybe even storing a list of 'motions' within my 'Sprite' object, then checking these on 'Update'...

Comment: @codinghands Yes that's a possibility, keeping it inside the object. But a more flexible solution would be to create a separate class, e.g. `Animator` which would keep these values, and you could use it for instance like: `Animator anim = new Animator(character, destination, duration);` and call `anim.Update(gameTime);` each frame. That's mostly a design decision and there are many ways to implement it.

Comment: That's even better. Learning a lot along the way here - many thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 4):

This are the meanings:

```
   t = TimeElapsed => Range[0, Duration]
   b = InitialValue;
   c = FinalValue - InitialValue;
   d = Duration;
```

I have a similar code to this for every easing function:

```
     public static partial class Tweening {    
        public static class Quartic {
            public static float EaseIn( float t, float b, float c, float d ) {
                return c * (t /= d) * t * t * t + b;
            }
            public static float EaseOut( float t, float b, float c, float d ) {
                return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
            }
            public static float EaseInOut( float t, float b, float c, float d ) {
                if ( (t /= d / 2) < 1 ) {
                    return c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b;
                }
                return -c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2) + b;
            }
        }
    }
```

And if you make an Animator class you can use a delegate method like this:

```
   public delegate float TweeningFunction( float timeElapsed, 
                                           float start, 
                                           float change, 
                                           float duration );
```

This way you can change easily the Animator behaviour changing the ease function...

```
   public Movement {
       public TweeningFunction Function;
       ....
   }

   MovementInstance.Function = Tweening.Quartic.EaseIn;
```

In this video I used this approach... you can see it at the code shown at first seconds..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QDeY15Ox-g