# Different types of smooth object movement

Tags: mathematics

In a game I have a specific object and two positions the object will move from and to.
I already have the function for calculating current position in specific time.

It works like this:

Inputting 0 will move the object to Position 1.

Inputting 1 will move the object to Position 2.

Inputting 0.5 will move the object in the middle of the two positions.

etc...

(In the examples below, time is varying from 0 to 1)
When I want to start the object slowly and stop it when it is moving fast, I use:

```
MoveObject(sin(time * 90))
```

When I want to start the object fast and stop it as it is getting slower, I use:

```
MoveObject(1 - cos(time * 90))
```

Without the effects, it's:

```
MoveObject(time)
```

How do I make the object start moving slowly, move fast in the center of two positions and then get slower while reaching the second position?

Comment: what about `MoveObject(sin(time * 180))`?

Comment: This type of method would vary from 0 to 1 then again to 0

Comment: Here's an interesting read about easing equations: http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/

Comment: so there is tanh function, but it needs some preparations before using... maybe `MoveObject((tanh(time * 180 - 90) + 1) / 2)`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for easing functions...

Here you have some desription:
http://www.gizma.com/easing/#expo1

I wrote a reply about them here with my own implemntation in C#

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26872/8390